# Trying to refactor an animation into a class object, how to construct its interrelating parts

Tags: javascript, object, refactoring

I'm trying to refactor some animation code into a class object so it can then be instantiated.

The original code was just a file with some functions and variables, and it called the variables from the functions, which is turning out to be a little bit of a problem since one of the things the code had was a constructor to populate an array.

I'm a little confused at how to put this aspect into the new class constructor function, since this mini class Particle has a method of its own called .use that has some ctx variables inside that. But how do they point to the ctx information thats contained in the rest of the function since all that is in another scope area?

I tried adding the .use method with a prototype like `DrawSlinky.prototype.Particle.use` and when it gets to the point where it should call this function, it says that it isn't a function, so I imagine that that didn't work.

Here's the code as it is right now, with the error following :

```js
DrawSlinky.prototype.Particle = function(x, y, color, area, velocity, rad){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.vx = Math.cos(rad) * velocity;
  this.vy = Math.sin(rad) * velocity;
  this.color = color;
  this.area = area;
  this.use = function(){
    this.x += this.vx *= .99;
    this.y += this.vy *= .99;
    this.ctx.fillStyle = ctx.shadowColor = this.color;
    this.ctx.shadowBlur = this.area;
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.area/2, 0, Math.PI*2);
    this.ctx.fill();
  }
};
```

This is giving me an error that the ctx property is not defined. How do I work around this and access the ctx information in the rest of the object outside of the .Particle mini constructor?

Comment: `this.constructor` refers to its *`super`*. I'm assuming you defined `ctx` in `DrawSlinky`?

Comment: @vihan1086

Yea -- `this.c = document.getElementById("c"),
    this.w = c.width,
    this.h = c.height,
    this.ctx = c.getContext('2d')`

Comment: So `this.constructor` didn't work?

Comment: so `this.DrawSlinky.ctx`?

Yeah, that did not work, same error

Comment: Just `this.constructor.ctx` you don't have to replace anything

Comment: Added as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

This is like dealing with `super` in other languages. To access `super` data, use:

```
this.constructor
```